# How can I prevent Excel from converting alphanumeric fields to dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, regional-settings

I'm exporting alphanumeric data from a SharePoint list (single line of text datatype), but when my Excel desktop app opens the file, it changes "7-3" to "07/03/2021" and displays it as "07-March". I know that the export is working correctly because if I open the file in Notepad++ instead of Excel I can see that the value is still "7-3".

This is what I see in SharePoint before I export:
[7-3 from SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG8Ds.png)

This is what I see when I view the exported CSV in Notepad++ :
["7-3" in Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HW0p.png)

But this is how it appears in Excel when I first open the file:
[07-Mar in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc1Tg.png)

And this is what I see if I edit the cell value in Excel:
[07/03/2021 in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK9IY.png)

I tried changing my regional settings to use a slash as a date separator instead of a dash, but that doesn't prevent Excel from seeing "7-3" as a date... it just makes Excel display that data as "07/03/2021" instead of "07-03-2021" in edit mode, as shown above. My point is not that I want it to be changed to a date with slashes, but that I want to retain the value I exported ("7-3").

I need to find a way to provide my users with a simple, predictable export/import process that keeps the data intact for a process that will be repeated many times, so it's not feasible to ask them to manually force the format for every column that may have this type of information every time they do an import. Is there a one-time setting/solution that will make Excel keep the existing alphanumeric data when opening a CSV file?

Comment: This is an age old complaint about Excel.  If you just open the text file, excel will always try to convert any text that looks like a date into a date.  It will convert the string 10E3 to 10000.  The only reliable way is to use the import wizard where you can set the column type as text during the import.  If the column is not set to Text BEFORE the data is inserted it will always try to convert.

Comment: One way is to edit the text file so that the character separating fields is followed  by a single quote. For example, if `,` is the separator, search and replace it to `,'`. Of course, all such columns will be text only, so you would need to *not* add the quote for numerical fields.

Comment: What version of Office did you use? If you can use Power Query in Excel, you can use from text feature in Power Query editor and change the column cell format: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/textcsv

Comment: So defining datatype in target worksheet will work if it's always the same worksheet, but the user can't just open the file, they'll need to go through the extra steps for the import wizard every time - extra training and time required. Search & Replace for the delimiter requires an extra step each time but would mess up fields which are actually dates, so likely wouldn't be feasible for me (the extra steps each time would be an issue even if it didn't mess up other date fields). I haven't used PowerQuery but will look into it. It's unfortunate there's not a setting to address this behavior!

Comment: What about distributing the data as Excel files (.xlsx or .xlsm)?

Comment: I don't think xlsm is an option (exporting from SharePoint 2016), but with xlsx the results are the same. I actually tried that first, then went to CSV hoping it would treated more generically, but Excel wants to "enhance" the content either way.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have gary.csv like:

[image]

Here 5-11 is a height in feet and inches and 174 is weight in pounds.

Rather than double-clicking the file to open it, use `Import Data` in the `Data Tab`.  Tell the Import Wizard the the field is text.  This results in:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't feasible in a large organization where users with limited technical knowledge expect to double-click to open a file. There's a high cost to training thousands of users to use the import wizard every time, provide support when they do it incorrectly, and find and fix errors when they forget. It also costs them time (compared to just opening directly) every time they open the file. It results in a huge amount of extra work for what "should" be simple in Excel - just show me the data I provided, the way I provided it. MS dropped the ball on this one.